# Returning (android.hardware.Camera) in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera, android-camera2

I am building an app that contains a video capture from a custom camera with a surface view. It works fine in portrait mode, but when I change to landscape mode the camera preview goes to a blank screen.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera_activity);

        camera1 = Camera.open(camId);
        try {
            camera1.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera1.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

In the `ConfigurationChanged` function I'm not getting the `camera1` Object.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) on handling orientation changes in Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the **camera1** object to survive Activity death-and-resurrection, or (less effocient) destroy the camera **onStop()** or (more efficient) keep the activity instance when configuration changes.